# pdflatex in terminal - how to define editor to jump to (instead of vim)?

Tags: errors, pdftex

When using pdflatex or latexmk in the Terminal (OS X) I can use the key "E" to jump to an error position in the sourcecode, if compiling hangs.

However, this opens vim in Terminal and I'm not familiar with that editor.

Where can I define which Editor to use in this case? I'd prefer Aquamacs or Emacs.

Comment: That feature was very handy a while back, when a compilation lasted for several hours. But today, you can go to `batchmode` and later edit the part or abort compilatioon and edit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`texdoc web2c` says

> `--with-editor=cmd`
>              Change the default editor invoked by the `e` interactive command. See
>              Section 3.5.3 [Editor invocation], page 12.

Page 12 says that as an alternative to the command line you can set the TEXEDIT environment variable to `emacs %s`

*Hint for those who don't know this (like the Original poster):* 
Setting the environment variable can be done with `export TEXEDIT="emacs %s"` in the Terminal

Comment: -1 for not using vi. `:)`

Comment: Use export TEXEDIT="emacs  +%d %s" to jump to the appropriate line as well.